# Post <Li> Items with Json and Jquery to Web Method

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am trying to pass a `<li>` list to a web method using json and Jquery. My goal is to return this list to C# using a Session Variable.My problem is that the session return always null. So the list never passes on Web Method.
The List:

```
<div>    
      <ol id="mycart">      
      <li>iPhone</li>
      <li>iPod</li>
      <li>iPad</li>
        </ol> 
         </div>
 <input type="button" id = "btngetCart" value="Get cart" />
```

The Json Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#btngetCart").live("click", function () {

            var items = $('.mycart').find('li').map(function() {
  var item = { };


  item.title = $(this).text();

  return item;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(items);

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',

                url: "WebForm4.aspx/GetCart",

                data: "{json}",

                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (r) {



                }

            });

        });

    </script>
```

The Web Method:

```
public class mycart
        {
            private string[] title;

        }
          [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static mycart GetCart(mycart title)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["j"] = title;
            return title;


        }
```

Comment: considering that it should be WebForm4.aspx GetCart which should be called, what is class mycart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error here :

```
html : <ol id="mycart">   has id attribute

var items = $('.mycart') //used class, which does not exists, try this:

var items = $('#mycart')

AND change 
data: "{json}",
to
data: json,
```

Comment: No still the Session return null

Comment: @focus, can you please look the network panel of the firebug, and examine the posted dat, whether posted correctly or not? and let me know

Comment: I have 0 requests . Like i never press btngetCart

Comment: Now, It posts the values but i take a message on firebug "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'title'."